# Return the height of node n of general tree ( recursion)

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures

I'm working on this challenge:

> Write a function `height(n, T)` to return the height of node `n` of tree `T`. Given is a Tree data structure (using two arrays) to store characters as labels and some operators.
>
> The tree `T` is encoded as a set of two arrays, where nodes are identified by indices in those two arrays (which have the same length). One array holds the labels of the nodes, and the other has the parent references as indices in the same arrays. A parent reference of -1 means the node is the root.

I tried several things, but can't solve this problem. For some cases the `height` function returns the correct answer, but for others not

My C code:

```c
int height(Node n, Tree *pT){ 
    // if invalid
    if ( n < 0 || n> pT->maxNode) return -1;
    if ( leftmostChild(n, pT) == NULL_NODE && rightSibling(leftmostChild(n,pT),pT) == NULL_NODE) return 0;
    //find 
    int L = height(leftmostChild(n, pT), pT);
    int R = height(rightSibling(leftmostChild(n, pT),pT), pT);
    if ( L > R) return L + 1;
    return R + 1;
}
```

This is the full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLENGTH 100
#define NULL_NODE -1
 
typedef int Node;
typedef char LabelType;
 
typedef struct {
    Node      P[MAXLENGTH];
    LabelType L[MAXLENGTH];
    int maxNode;
} Tree;

Node leftmostChild(Node n, Tree *pT){
    if ( n < 0 || n > pT->maxNode) return NULL_NODE;
    for ( Node i = n + 1; i <= pT->maxNode; i++){
        if ( pT->P[i] == n )  return i;
    }
    return NULL_NODE;
}

Node rightSibling(Node n, Tree *pT){
    if ( n < 0 || n > pT->maxNode) return NULL_NODE;
    for ( Node i = n + 1; i <= pT->maxNode; i++){
        if ( pT->P[i] == pT->P[n] )  return i;
    }
    return NULL_NODE;
}
 
int height(Node n, Tree *pT){
    if ( n < 0 || n>pT->maxNode) return -1;
    if ( leftmostChild(n, pT) == NULL_NODE && rightSibling(leftmostChild(n,pT),pT) == NULL_NODE) return 0;
    int L = height(leftmostChild(n,pT), pT);
    int R = height(rightSibling(leftmostChild(n,pT),pT), pT);
    if ( L > R) return L + 1;
    return R + 1;
}
 
int main(){
    Tree T = { {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 10, 9, 4, 7, 5},
    {'S', 'L', 'K', 'J', 'A', 'V', 'R', 'E', 'F', 'T', 'C', 'X', 'U', 'I', 'H', 'D'}, 15};
    for (int i = 0; i <= T.maxNode; i++)
        printf("height(%d) = %d\n", i, height(i, &T));
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
height(0) = 4
height(1) = 2
height(2) = 1
height(3) = 3
height(4) = 1
height(5) = 2
height(6) = 2
height(7) = 1
height(8) = 0
height(9) = 1
height(10) = 1
height(11) = 0
height(12) = 0
height(13) = 0
height(14) = 0
height(15) = 0
```

Current, wrong output:

```
height(0) = 3
height(1) = 2
height(2) = 1
height(3) = 3
height(4) = 1
height(5) = 2
height(6) = 2
height(7) = 1
height(8) = 0
height(9) = 1
height(10) = 1
height(11) = 0
height(12) = 0
height(13) = 0
height(14) = 0
height(15) = 0
```

You can also see it run on [ideone](https://ideone.com/0iCGpT).

Comment: int height(Node n, Tree *pT){

Comment: and full code in link : https://ideone.com/0iCGpT

Comment: Looking at your ideone link your tree structure isn't a tree, it's a flat array of numbers. How are you defining depth? Is that array an encoding of a binary tree somehow?

Comment: Is each number the number of its parent node? That doesn't match your expected output though. Why would height(11) be 0, because 11 isn't in the array? But if so why would height(0) be 4? There are four zeros in the array.

Comment: Is the height of a node the same as the height of a subtree rooted at that node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your `height` function:

- In the second `if` statement, if the first condition is true, then you shouldn't need to call `rightSibling` at all, but return 0 anyhow when that is true. Also, when the first condition is *not* true, it is irrelevant whether there is a right sibling or not, and the return value should certainly not be 0.
- Your code is expecting the tree to be a *binary* tree, but this is not guaranteed. A node can have more than two children, and so you need to iterate *all* siblings. For this you could use a `for` loop.

Corrected version:

```
int height(Node n, Tree *pT){
    if ( n < 0 || n>pT->maxNode) return -1;
    int h = -1;
    for (int child = leftmostChild(n, pT); child != NULL_NODE; child = rightSibling(child, pT)) {
        int childHeight = height(child, pT);
        h = h < childHeight ? childHeight : h;
    }
    return h + 1;
}
```